# android including layout with <include> tag , but any onclick functionality is not working

Tags: java, android, include

I have a navigation drawer in my app and one included layout. but when I run the app every image and button with onClickListener not working. in the below code, navigationDrawer code is not included because I want the other buttons to be clicked. I don't know if there is invisible layout which blocks everything or what

**main Activity Layout with include tag**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_dg_main_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_drawer_menu_header"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**this this another layout (content_dg_main_2) with button and images**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_my_speedo_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNavMenu"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu"
            android:tint="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUpgrade"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_upgrade"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:tint="@color/colorBNBSelected" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Video Recorder"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivUpgrade"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivNavMenu"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="consume"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clHeader">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btnstart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:onClick="onclick"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnstop"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="482:317"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00:00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnstart" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_gallery"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_border_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTimer"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/gallryicon"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gallery"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="28dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gallryicon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_setting"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/green_border_bg"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_gallery"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingicon"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Setting"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="28dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/settingicon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnstop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="stop service"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnstart" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/adViewFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_setting" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**java code**

```
startButton = findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
navMenuImageView = findViewById(R.id.ivNavMenu);
upgradeImageView = findViewById(R.id.ivUpgrade);
timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(MainDGAActivity.this, "start button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});

navMenuImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
});

upgradeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Create a dialog to display the upgrade layout
        final Dialog upgradeDialog = new Dialog(MainDGAActivity.this);
        upgradeDialog.setContentView(R.layout.purchase_dg_dialog); // Replace with your upgrade layout XML file

        // Optionally, set dialog properties like background, title, etc.
        // For example:
       /* upgradeDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        upgradeDialog.setTitle("Upgrade");*/

        // Add any logic or UI interactions related to your upgrade screen here

        // Add a button to close the dialog
        Button closeButton = upgradeDialog.findViewById(R.id.closeButton);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                upgradeDialog.dismiss(); // Close the dialog when the close button is clicked
            }
        });

        // Show the dialog
        upgradeDialog.show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have taken your code of content_dg_main_2 and done some changes.

content_dg_main_2 code is here

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_my_speedo_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    >
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/clHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivNavMenu"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/products"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<!--        android:tint="@color/black"-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivUpgrade"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/imagegallery"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:text="Video Recorder"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivUpgrade"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ivNavMenu"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<!--    <Button-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/button"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
<!--        android:onClick="consume"-->
<!--        android:text="Button"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
<!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/clHeader">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btnstart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="482:317"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6" />
            <!--            android:onClick="onclick"-->
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTimer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="00:00:00"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnstart" />
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_gallery"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvTimer"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/gallryicon"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gallery"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="28dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/gallryicon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_setting"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_gallery"
                app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.6">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/settingicon"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Setting"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="28dp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/settingicon"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnstop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:text="stop service"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnstart" />
<!--            android:visibility="gone"-->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/adViewFrameLayout"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/layout_setting" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the main activity code is here where i have implemented setOnClickListeners.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button startBtn;
    ImageView navMenuImageView, upgradeImageView;
    TextView timerTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
        navMenuImageView = findViewById(R.id.ivNavMenu);
        upgradeImageView = findViewById(R.id.ivUpgrade);
        timerTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);

        //1
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Start Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //2
        navMenuImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nav Menu ImageView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        //3
        upgradeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upgrade ImageView Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });



    }
}
```

and these 3 onClickListeners works fine.